# Using X server without opening display

Tags: xorg

Is there a way to connect to and use X server without calling XOpenDisplay? For example, is it possible to use X rendering capabilities to render to a bitmap? Does all interaction must start with XOpenDisplay?

Comment: State what you're trying to do. This question is vague at best.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Asking an X server to do things for you necessarily requires talking to an X server.

You can create virtual X servers (connected to no video or input hardware, just rendering into memory) with the `Xvfb` X server.